# How do I encapsulate PHP variables in a string? (in POST request body)

Tags: php, string, curl

I want to have this body:

```
{
 "name": "sales_support",
 "description": "The sales support team",
 "parentOrgUnitPath": "/corp/support",
 }
```

In a PHP curl post request.

How do I add the variables into this line properly?

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{ "name":"' .$createOUname '","description":"' .$description '","parentOrgUnitPath":"'.$parentOUpath'"},
```

I have tried it like this but then I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''","description":"'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'
```

What did I do wrong in my code? I cant get hold of how to resolve this

Comment: don't write json string by hand, that's why there's `json_encode` function in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array with variables,and send `json_encode()` data to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

```
$postFields = array(
    "name"  =>  $createOUname,
    "description"   =>  $description,
    "parentOrgUnitPath" =>  $parentOUpath
)
```

And then

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postFields),
```

Comment: $body = array(
     "name" => $createOUname,
     "description" => $description,
     "parentOrgUnitPath" => $parentOUpath
); this did it for me thanks

Comment: @user3660293  yes, missed variable. updated now. check pls